# Teradata SQL assistant : Counting distinct values in a table based on cumulative sum

Tags: sql, teradata

Teradata SQL: I'm trying to count the number of distinct customer_ids in a table contributing to a sale last year. And I just want the count of customers comprising of top 80% of sales. There's no Top function in Teradata sql assistant and I tried using count. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: There is `SELECT TOP 90 PERCENT` syntax in Teradata...

Comment: I'm using the teradata sql assistant. And the "top 80% percent" is not supported.

Comment: Please post your query, even if it doesn't execute, along with the errors you receive.